# Disable CSS for responsive design

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have the following CSS setup up on my site. I'd like for it to be disabled when a browser width gets narrower than 900 px, but to remain enabled when a browser width is greater than 900. Any suggestions on how I can do this?

Thanks!

```
.image-slide-title {
  display: block !important;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1;
  z-index: 2000;
  font-family: "open sans";
  font-size: 100%;
  font-weight: 100;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
  line-height: 1.8;
  color: #333
}
```

Comment: write a media query and just write reset css into the same for all the elements. Do not forget to mark those important as only then the reset behavoiur in your case would work

Comment: It's not that I don't want to help you, but this is one of the first things you see if you do some basic research on responsive web design. Google is your friend, and so are other search engines.

Comment: Thanks guys. @RaptorDotCpp Lol, I tried searching but I didn't find anything I can understand. Figured someone here would be happy to help  with a simple suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to add the html tag for smaller devices:

**HTML**

put the following meta inside your page head

```
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1" />
```

**CSS**

```
.image-slide-title {
          display: block !important;
          height: 100%;
          width: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          top: 1;
          z-index: 2000;
          font-family: "open sans";
          font-size: 100%;
          font-weight: 100;
          margin-bottom: 100px;
          line-height: 1.8;
          color: #333
        }

     @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
          .image-slide-title {
             /* do what you want here */
             display: none !important;
          }
      }
```

Honestly, if you can remove the important tag, it will be much more simpler to manage the responsive effect

Comment: Also, if you want to create a responsive design for all devices, you can find many online website that will help you: http://www.responsinator.com/
Note: most website aren't emulators, so the result might be different depending on the device (blackberry IOS sucks)

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're looking for media queries.

```
@media (max-width: 899px) {
    .image-slide-title {
        display: none !important;
    }
}
```

Don't forget to do this on your html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
```

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is to create a secondary css page for your mobile.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 901px)" href="style.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 900px)" href="mobile-style.css" />
```

Then in that stylesheet have the settings specific to that.

Comment: Thanks, Cam! Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to add media query

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
  .div-name {
    width: max-content !important;
  }
}
```

This usage avoid to rescale your flex system and you achieve a solid structure does not effect screen resizing